# how to set limit and offset with get parameters

Tags: yii

I have three models named:

1. content
2. category
3. contentCategory

and between content and category is a `MANY_MANY` relation like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'contents'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Content',
                'tbl_content_category(category_id, content_id)',
                'order'=>'contents.id DESC',
                'limit'=>'10',
                'offset'=>'30',
        ),
    );
}
```

and it work well. but I want to set `offset` parameter from `$_GET` variables. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set

```
'limit'=> Yii::app()->request->getQuery('limit', 10),
'offset'=> Yii::app()->request->getQuery('offset', 30),
```

Comment: Or look into CActiveDataProvider and its pagination system. It will do all if that for you automatically